# PHP Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead

Tags: php

Error: Depreciated

```
 if( preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match) ) {
            $match[1] = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

How to use preg_replace_callback instead of preg_replace ? I tried to replace the preg_replace and got another error.

> PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'strtoupper("\0")', to be a valid callback in

Answer (score 1):

preg_replace_callback() should specify a exact callback.
Check more about preg_replace_callback() here: [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
if( preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match) ) {
            $match[1] = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', function ($matches) {
            return strtoupper("\0");
        }, strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

Comment: Thanks, Got another error message : PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback in

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an actual callback. Try the following:

```
 if( preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match) ) {
            $match[1] = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', function($matches){return strtoupper("\0");}, strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

A callback can be either an anonymous function like above or a name of a function as a string.

**Note:** `\e` modifier was DEPRECATED in [php-5.5](/questions/tagged/php-5.5), and REMOVED as of [php-7.0](/questions/tagged/php-7.0), you must use `preg_replace_callback`, anywhere where you would use `\e`. learn more about it here. [Can someone explain the /e regex modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986331/can-someone-explain-the-e-regex-modifier)

Comment: Thanks, Got another error message :  PHP Warning:  preg_replace_callback(): Modifier /e cannot be used with replacement callback in

Comment: Just remove the `/e` from your regex. You are using `preg_replace_callback()`, so there is no need for that.

Comment: `\e` is deprecated, learn more about it here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986331/can-someone-explain-the-e-regex-modifier

Answer (score 0):

Signature of `preg_replace_callback` from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

`mixed preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] )`

You need to pass a callback function as the second argument.

```
  $html = $_POST['html'];

  // uppercase headings
  $html = preg_replace_callback(
    '(<h([1-6])>(.*?)</h\1>)',
    function ($m) {
        return "<h$m[1]>" . strtoupper($m[2]) . "</h$m[1]>";
    },
    $html
  );
```