# What means e in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, mod-headers

I want to add a non-parameter canonical link to all parametrized URLs. I try to do this on the following way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

### Catching all URLs with non-empty parameter ###
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . 

### Adding to all parametrized URLs an environment variable ###
    RewriteRule .* : [E=MY_HEAD:1]

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>

### Setting a non-parametrized URL as canonical to all URLs with an environment variable
    Header set Link '%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}e; rel="canonical"' env=MY_HEAD

</IfModule>
```

My question is: looking for examples i found results with and without the `e` after `{REQUEST_URI}`. What means this `e` in this context?

Answer (score 2):

The `e` is the syntax used by `mod_headers` to reference an environmental variable:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#Header

> %{VARNAME}e   The contents of the environment variable VARNAME.

---

*Note: I know this is old, but I had the same question and the PHP answer is of no relevance to htaccess.*

Answer (score 1):

The e Regex Modifier in PHP.

The e modifier is a deprecated regex modifier which allows you to use PHP code within your regular expression. This means that whatever you parse in will be evaluated as a part of your program.

and also you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986331/can-someone-explain-the-e-regex-modifier)

Comment: Does it mean, that this code doesn't work without the `e` and examples without it are erroneous?