# Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'word(\1)', to be a valid callback in /.php on line 54

Tags: php

I have warning in php in this line

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/LANG\[([0-9a-z_]*?)\]/e','word(\\1)',$read);
```

how to fix this issue

Comment: The `/e` flag was removed in PHP 7...

Comment: So do I have to remove it ? Because it was third party script not me I have built it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matched group is passed to callback function by default.
So your code should be like this.

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/LANG\[([0-9a-z_]*?)\]/','word',$read);
```

In your callback you can access matched group like this.

```
function word($matches)
  {
   //$matches[0] will be while matched string
   //$matches[1] will be your first matched group
   }
```

> /e flag was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.5.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0

So, avoid using `/e` flag. 
For more information it's worth have look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986331/can-someone-explain-the-e-regex-modifier)